# How to prevent sending a text message for the second time if the first attempt was successful in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I have some records in a database and if count of a particular id is more than 4 then I want to send SMS to that particular field phone. But if the first attempt to send is successful, I don't want to send any subsequent messages to that particular number again.

I have tried using:

```
if( file_exist($url) ) {
 die( 'already sent' );
}

file_put_content( $url, 1 );

// A lot of code

unlink( $url );
```

But it is not working.

```
    $reminderQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM acceptance WHERE clientID = '$clientID' "; 
    $reminderresult = $pdo->prepare($reminderQuery); 
    $reminderresult->execute(); 
    $number_of_rows = $reminderresult->fetchColumn(); 
    if($number_of_rows > 4){
      $remindersms= "SELECT *  FROM clients WHERE id = '$clientID'  ";
      $remindersendsms = $pdo->prepare($remindersms);
     $remindersendsms->execute();
    while ($remindersmsnoti = $remindersendsms->fetch()){

  $phoneNos = $remindersmsnoti['phone'];

  $key = "*******************";  // Remember to put your own API Key here
  $phoneNo = $phoneNos;
  $message = "*******************";
$sender_id = "YENKOR"; //11 Characters maximum


//encode the message
$msg = urlencode($message);

//prepare your url
$url = "*********************";

$response = file_get_contents($url) ;


}


    }
```

I want the above code not to send any messages again after the SMS has been sent.

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Comment: You need to pass `$clientID` as a parameter.

Comment: Is a variable am getting from a session but is not part like now. because I wanted to shorten the code

Comment: Why did you shorten the code? You might have broken your own code by doing so.

Comment: @kateorlova Please don't add the tags to the title in your suggested edits. There is dedicated space for tags.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a column `sms_sent` to the clients table initially set to 0 (although, you might want to set it to 1 for those client who already have 4 or more records on the acceptance table on the assumption that sms messages have already been sent for them). Then change your initial SQL to:

```
select * from clients c join (
   select clientId from acceptance having count(*) >= 4
 ) a on c.id = a.clientId and not c.sms_sent
```

This will select all clients with 4 or more records on the `acceptance` table who have not had the sms message sent (if you want just a specific client as in your example, you can add the additional condition). Then when you successfully send the sms message, you update the `sms_sent` column to 1 for the client on the `clients` table.

As a side note, since you are already using a prepared statement, any parameters you want to pass should be done thus to avoid SQL Injection attacks:

```
$reminderQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM acceptance WHERE clientID = ?"; 
$reminderresult = $pdo->prepare($reminderQuery); 
$reminderresult->execute(array($clientId());
```

The above assumes that $clientId is a string. If not then you have to use `bindValue` ([See PDOStatement::bindValue)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)